# Get current currency rates automatically with a currency converter apps?

Tags: android

I am creating a currency converter app.  I know that the value of currencies constantly change, so I was wondering if there is a way to access the Internet in my app to get current rates, and incorporate them into the app seamlessly?

Thank you.

### Update

I think my question is being slightly misunderstood. Getting the actual current currency rates is not what is hard for me; the hard part is writing the code to do so. Can someone put me in the right direction and help me understand how to write the code to incorporate them into an app?

Comment: Did you check out this post on [currency converter and historical rates app in Android](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/forexwiz/)? ... pretty close to what you might want to achieve.

Comment: You can refer this you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35195078/2866716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing exactly what you are doing, though my main intention is to write a tutorial for the same. Here's a nice place from where you can get all the information about the exchange rate.

http://josscrowcroft.github.com/open-exchange-rates/

They update the data every hour and return the information in json format.

Have fun :)

*Update to the UPDATE*

Alright, so you need to read up on the following things and incorporate them in your code,

1. Receiving the data can be done by either HttpUrlConnection/Apache Http Client. (Make sure you do all your long running tasks, ie downloading data in a separate thread)
2. Most of the returned data, is usually received as XML or JSON. You need to write parsers  using the classes present in Android. XmlPullParser/Dom Parser for XML or JSONObjects for JSON. Enough info is present in the Android Developer site to do that.
3. Once you parse the data, the nhow you design and present it is totally upto you.

Hope this helps you in moving ahead.

Comment: Okay thank you for this information. I appreciate this. Just a side note, in case you happen to have a Blackberry Playbook, be sure to try out my app when it comes out :). It will be called The Ultimate Currency Converter.

Comment: why this url not open? http://josscrowcroft.github.com/open-exchange-rates/

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo finance will return this information for you quite easily. Can't guarantee that they'll provide this forever, but it seems to have worked for years.

You just use the following URL and for each currency you want to convert you put it in the url like this example:

`http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDEUR=x,JPYCNY=x&f=l1`

This will return a CSV of the value of 1 USD in Euros (USDEUR=x), and 1 Japanese Yen in Yuan Renminbi (JPYCNY=x).

Just comma delimit each pair of currencies you want a result for.

You can also get some extra information by adding some extra symbols to the &f part, though I don't have them on hand. You should be able to search for the codes though.

Comment: Okay, but can you specifically show the code needed to use this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for idea, base on your country, get the your national bank rates. Look for any feeds, if any, otherwise, try to parse their website table of rates. This reasoning is based on my assumption that there exists such site. Re-query that site, each time the app is started and internet connection is available.

If you are targeting international usage, then try to find some reliable sources from where you'll leech this information.

If you are looking for HTML parser library, google JSoup.