# How to pass customized amount to yahoo currency converter API

Tags: php, currency, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, currency-exchange-rates

I am using yahoo currency converter API in my Application. But it gives the currency exchange rate only. I am not able to pass my customized amount to API.
The below is the API Request i am using

```
 https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from   yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('INRUSD')&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

How will i pass the amount in about request query? Any Idea?

Example: I need to convert 1000 INR to USD. So i will pass amount 1000 INR to Yahoo currency converter API and result should be 15 USD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using another currency converter ([xe.com](http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1000&From=INR&To=USD)), it should be $14.99

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19848392/3000179